# Select all locations recursively from table MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, recursive-query

I am trying to do the following query, where a user has a `location_id` and that location table is recursive.

```
Locations
========
id
name
level
parent_id

Users
=====
id
name
location_id
```

Is there any way I can get all levels of the locations in one query?

Comment: You can, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7324296/18565

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the Options for Storing Hierarchical Data in a Relational Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

Comment: You could modify [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31967073) answer of mine for your purposes